# Best Python Web Framework for my API Server Needs

Tags: python, mysql, api, frameworks

I am working on developing two systems:

1. A system that will constantly retrieve economic data from a 3rd party data feed and push it into a MySQL DB (using sqlalchemy)
2. A server that will allow anyone to query the data in the db over a JSON AJAX API (similar to Yelp or Yahoo API for example)

I have two main questions:

1. Which Python framework should I use in 2)? Pyramid is my first choice, but if you strongly suggest against it or in favor of something else like Django or Pylons I am definitely wiling to consider it.
2. Should I develop the two system separately? Or should 1) be a part of 2), running within the framework (using crontab or celery for example)?

Comment: I suggest running django with pistons. That will give you a good RESTful platform that'll handle json out the box.

Comment: Regarding 2: it seems the system is small enough to have them in one project. However, if you anticipate the web end to grow, rather have it in a separate project. That way the upgrades won't disrupt the data collection tool.

Comment: Thanks! Why would I want to use REST in 2) instead of SOAP, or plain JSON? I am not really sure which will be better..

Comment: +1 on django with piston. Piston handles the requests under the hood for you and lets your easily just define urls and an easy CRUD style handler. It event out of the box will just map the actions to your models for you. Has built in auth. Plus there is django-authkey that generates api keys for piston. Its far less work to set up multi format apis with piston. Supports json xml yaml or even lets you write your own emitter

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what stage you are at, I would suggest to develop 2 systems because the load to pull data from 3rd party and the load to handle the API would be different.  You can scale them into a different types of nodes if you want.

Django-Tastypie (https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) is not bad, it supports all JSON, XML and YAML.  Also you can add OAuth easily.  Though, Django itself maybe a bit heavy for your needs at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the response! First, I see what you are saying about having two different systems. However, initially, these systems will be running on the same machine and over the same database. Doesn't having the same application access the DB, both for 1) and 2) make the DB access a lot faster compared to having 2 applications access it? And I also agree about Django - I like it, but I feel like it is more designed for systems like wikipedia that require management and so forth. Is Django really what I am looking for?

Comment: If I'm prototyping or building an alpha, I would just write one app, but leave the door open to split it into two.  And in terms of the speed of access, I think you are right if you plan to use a single DB, 1 app makes it runs relatively faster. But you should replicate a copy of the DB from #1 (read/write) to read-only for #2 every now and then for beta or production.

I'm not suggesting or pushing for Django, but I liked tastypie because the amount of time you need to spend is absolutely minimal to get a decent looking API up and running. Also to consider Flask, it is lightweight and fast.

Comment: Django isnt necc geared towards one kind of a system or another. Its like having sqlalchemy but with a bunch of other features like templates, url routing, etc. use what you want and ignore the rest. I think it contains everything you need in one place to design your models once and supply an api front end to it. You can write command line scripts that reuse the models as well and feed the database in various ways

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [web2py's](http://www.web2py.com) new functionality for easily generating [RESTful API's](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/09#RESTful-Web-Services), particularly its [parse_as_rest](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/09#parse_as_rest-%28experimental%29) and [smart_query](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/09#smart_query-%28experimental%29) functions. You might also consider using web2py's [database abstraction layer](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06) to handle #1.

If you need any help, ask on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Comment: Adding a note saying you're a core contributor for web2py would be nice.

Comment: First, I wouldn't describe myself as a *core* contributor (though I do make contributions). Second, why? I'm not expressing opinions or critiquing alternatives. I merely provided a few links detailing functionality that may suit the need, which the OP can easily evaluate to decide whether it's a viable option. My status is irrelevant.

Comment: Because I haven't seen too many people that work on product X recommend product Y where X and Y are competing products. That's why it's called a biased opinion. And that's why it's general practice to add a disclaimer.

And jeez, I wasn't trying to offend you or anything, merely making an observation.

Comment: Likewise, I wasn't trying to offend you, merely making an observation that a disclaimer wasn't really warranted here.

Comment: I see you didn't respond to my comment about biased opinion.

Comment: Where's the bias? Are you saying that web2py's RESTful API functionality and database abstraction layer cannot in fact handle this job? You might have a point if I had said something like, "web2py is the best tool for the job," or, "Stay away from Django." But I was just pointing to one option, and the OP can easily evaluate whether it is suitable for his needs without reference to my credentials. Anyway, perhaps you have something better to do than police 10 month old posts for borderline "disclaimer" infractions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Anthony, you should look at Web2Py. It is very easy to get started, very low learning cure and easy to deploy on many systems including Linux, Windows and Amazon.

So far I have found nothing that Web2Py can not do. But more importantly it does things how you would think they should be done, so if you are not sure, very often a guess is good enough and it just works. If you do get stuck, it has by far the best and most up to date documentation for any Python Web Framework.

Even with all it's great features, easy use and up to date documentation, you will also find that the web2py user group on Google, is like having a paid for help desk staffed 24 hours a day. Most questions are answered with a couple minutes and Massimo (The original creator of Web2Py) goes out of his way not only to help, but to implement new ideas, suggestions and bug fixes within days of them being raised in the group.